# URGENT - Can't checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

AFAIK there is nothing that has been changed over the last week but for some reason checkout is not possible, I've whittled it down to a problem in op_checkout.js::Review::nextStep:

```
nextStep: function(transport){
    console.log('opcheckout.js => Review::nextStep');
    //console.log(transport);
    //console.log(transport.responseText);
    if (transport) {
        console.log(transport); // THE PROBLEM
        try{
            response = eval('(' + transport.responseText + ')'); //FAILS 
        }
        catch (e) {
            response = {}; // GOES HERE
        }
        if (response.redirect) {
            this.isSuccess = true;
            location.href = response.redirect;
            return;
        }
        if (response.success) {
            this.isSuccess = true;
            window.location=this.successUrl;
        }
        else{
            var msg = response.error_messages;
            if (typeof(msg)=='object') {
                msg = msg.join("\n");
            }
            if (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        }

        if (response.update_section) {
            $('checkout-'+response.update_section.name+'-load').update(response.update_section.html);
        }

        if (response.goto_section) {
            checkout.gotoSection(response.goto_section, true);
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: can you share your site url?

Comment: did you check error log folder  for the errors `var/log` and also check script error in console.

Comment: I did check error log folder but theres no errors, how do I check script error in console?

Comment: If you have any order exporting module make sure that it has permissions to write (if it would use some events it can block order placing in case of exception). 

Are you sure there wasn't even a slight change maybe more then a week ago, but someone forgot to clean caches or something?
Any weird things in logs or something that could point into direction of an attack? 
Try: If this bug occurs also on your staging env. try changing there to default theme and check if problem persists. We have to narrow down the source of this problem first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by doing the following;

**In app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
Replace the line number 81 in info.phtml**

**with**

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```